# Copied a post to move it, and it is now on pastebin?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on Stack Overflow earlier but was advised to move it to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/818142/sudo-suddenly-not-working-correctly-on-os-x). I copied and pasted from one to the other. I have just noticed that the exact question I asked (and subsequently copy/pasted) is now on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1HUHkn6s) and was apparently added there by 'A Guest' an hour ago. The same time I copied the question. Only the sections formatted as code blocks appear on pastebin. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Don't be too surprised that code you post to an open web site visited by millions of programmers has a knack for multiplying :)

Comment: No, I get that :) I just found it peculiar that only the code-block sections were copied, as opposed to the whole question.

Comment: How should we know who copied your code for what reasons? Evidently somebody did just that, but as long as the specific user doesn't show up here and shares his reasons, we can only offer baseless speculations.

Comment: I asked because I wasn't certain 'somebody' was doing just that, I was curious (naively it seems) if there was some sort of relationship/link between Stack Overflow and pastebin.

Answer (score 3):

Your question on Super User was posted on *2014-09-29 09:44:06Z*, the pastebin was posted on *Monday 29th of September 2014 04:47:01 AM CDT*. So the pastebin was posted 3 minutes later.

Someone who saw your question put the code on pastebin for some reason. There's nothing special going on.